# Is my Azure Functions application configured to run in process or out of process (isolated)?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm approaching an existing Azure Functions project

I know in AzFuncs 4.0 we can run .Net 6 apps in either in process mode (running in the same context as the AzFunc runtime), or isolated mode (separate process, which allows for flexibility such as running on a different version of the framework).

How can I tell what processing model it's using?

Answer (score 10):

The answer lies in the values of the configuration variable FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME.

- `dotnet` => in process
- `dotnet-isolated` => out of process (isolated)

This can be found locally in `local.settings.json`. You may have to get this file from your colleagues because it's usually added to the .gitignore file for the project.

If it's deployed, check the values under the Azure Functions Configuration settings.

[image: Configuration Settings in Azure Portal]

Comment: Also: `.csproj` file will have property `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`. There will also be a `Program.cs` present with a `Main` method or not. "Isolated" Functions are kinda .NET Console Apps.